# About system of linear equation over subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$
\text { Let } V \text { denote a homogeneous system of } m \text { linear }
$ equations in $n$ unknowns over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers. Let $V(\mathbb{Q})$ denote the set
of solutions over $\mathbb{Q}$ . Let $F$ be any field of characteristic $0,$ then note that $\mathbb{Q} \subset F,$ and so
it makes sense to think of $V$ as a system of equations over $F ;$ let $V(F)$ denote the set of
solutions over $F$ . Show that
$$
V(\mathbb{Q}) \text { is infinite if and only if } V(F) \text { is infinite. }
$$

One side is easy to prove that if $Q$ has infinite solution then $F$ has infinite solution since $Q$ is subfield of $F$.

For other side we know if we have one solution over $F$ then we have solution over $Q$ since system of linear equation is over $Q$. But then I stuck?

Comment: Do you know tensor products?

Comment: Yes I know it @Bernard

Comment: Is it necessary to use Tensor product here?

Comment: With tensor products, the proof is hardly worth writing it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_\Bbb Q$ be the matrix over $\Bbb Q$ such that $v \in V(\Bbb Q) \iff A_\Bbb Q v = 0$.

Let $A_F$ be the matrix over $F$ such that $v \in V(F) \iff A_F v = 0$.

Then, $V(\Bbb Q)$ is infinite iff $\operatorname{nul} A_\Bbb Q > 0$ iff $\operatorname{nul} A_F > 0$ iff $V(F)$ is infinite.

The middle equivalence holds because $A_\Bbb Q$ and $A_F$ are really the "same" matrix; they can undergo the same row operations to get to the same matrix in RREF, and the nullity is $n$ minus the number of pivots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The linear system $V$ corresponds a linear map $\;\varphi:\mathbf Q^n\longrightarrow \mathbf Q^m$, and $V(\mathbf Q)$ is simply  $\ker\varphi$.

Consider the exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow\ker\varphi\longrightarrow\mathbf Q^n\xrightarrow{\enspace\varphi\enspace}\mathbf Q^m $$
and tensor with $F$.